# create accordion UI for the SP Online newform.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-online, newform, accordion

am trying to create a accordion like UI form for my SPO list newform.aspx 
by following the below URL : https://spjsblog.com/category/accordion/

but am unable to get anything working!
has anyone tried with creation of accordion for their newform.aspx and editform.aspx in SPO list UI?

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js">
      </script>
     <script type="text/javascript" 
src="/test/English/Javascript/Accordion/v2.0/AccordionForSharePointForms.js">
      </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

   var accConstructor = {sections:[{name:’First section’,fields:
   [‘InMultipleSections’,’Column1′,’Column2′],mouseOver:’This is the first 
    section’,sectionStyle:”,clickFunction:”},
      {name:’Second section’,fields:
   [‘InMultipleSections’,’Column3′,’Column4′,’Lookup1′,’MyMultiLookup’],
    mouseOver:’
    This is the second 
  section’,sectionStyle:”,clickFunction:’secondSectionClick(this)’},
     {name:’Third section’,fields:
     [‘InMultipleSections’,’Title’],mouseOver:’This is 
     the third section’,sectionStyle:”,clickFunction:”},
         {name:’Forth section’,fields:
    [‘Column5′,’Column6′,’MyPeoplePicker’],mouseOver:’This is the forth 
       section’,sectionStyle:”,clickFunction:”},
    {name:’Attachments’,fields:
    [‘attachments’],mouseOver:”,sectionStyle:”,clickFunction:”}],
     settings:{viewAllFields:{show:true,position:’bottom’,name:’All 
    fields’,mouseOver:’This section shows all 
     fields’,sectionStyle:”,clickFunction:”},
    orphanFields:{show:true,name:’Orphans’,mouseOver:’All orphan 
    fields’,sectionStyle:”,clickFunction:”},
```

Comment: The blog-post clearly states that this is for SP on-premise 2010 or 2007.

Comment: has anyone explored creating the accordion UI for SPO list, with single line of tetx, multline, dropdown, and people picker controls? any links ?

Comment: You realize the code you pasted here is exactly the code from the blog post, which references file locations (`src="/test/English/Javascript/...` etc) and column names (`Column1`, `Column2`, `MyMultiLookup`, etc.) which are very likely not in your environment?

Answer (score 1):

We can use the [HillbillyTemplate.js](https://github.com/mrackley/HillbillyTemplate) library and jQuery UI to achieve it.

The code like below.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> 
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/themes/start/jquery-ui.css" > 
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../SiteAssets/HillbillyTemplate.js"></script> 
<style type="text/css">  
.ms-formtable{display:none;}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var tabsObj = [ 
        ["General", ["Title", "column1", "column2"]], 
        ["Admin", ["column3", "column4"]],
        ["Misce", ["column5", "column6"]]
    ];
    buildAccordion(tabsObj);
    $().HillbillyTemplate({
        genericAlert: true,
        alertErrorText: "Form errors exist. Please fix form errors and try again"
    });
    $("#accordion").accordion();
});
function buildAccordion(tabsObj){
    for(var i=0;i<tabsObj.length;i++){
        var section=tabsObj[i][0];
        var columns=tabsObj[i][1];
        var accordionHTML="<h3>"+section+"</h3><div><p><table>";
        for(var j=0;j<columns.length;j++){
            accordionHTML+="<tr><td>"+columns[j]+":</td><td><span class='hillbillyForm' data-displayName='"+columns[j]+"'></span></td></tr>";
        }
        accordionHTML+="</table></p></div>";
        $("#accordion").append(accordionHTML);
    }
}
</script>
<span class="hillbillyFormSave"></span>
<span class="hillbillyFormCancel"></span>
<div id="accordion">   
</div>
```

Refer to: [SharePoint Online List Accordion for my NewForm.aspx or EditForm.aspx](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/msonline/en-US/7c02b398-a363-40fb-84fd-d803493c988d/sharepoint-online-list-accordion-for-my-newformaspx-or-editformaspx?forum=onlineservicessharepoint)

Comment: i agree that, it can be created. am having few more reqmnts within the form, i wanna add 2 buttons within the sections and manipulate the  list data of sections and send email. is it possible? adding a new button immediately below sections only for 5,6,7 sections ( i am having 7 sections for this splist)